# How to convert database column type without losing any existing data?

Tags: postgresql, ddl, alter-table

I want to change the datatype of a column which already has some data. The data should not be lost. How can I convert it?

Comment: `alter table alter column`.  Data will only be lost if the types are not compatible.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the current table definition (as a `create table` statement) and the desired new data type. In general, altering the type will not cause any data loss. ([edit] your question, do no post code in comments and [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `ALTER TABLE` statement.

If the conversion to the new values cannot be done with an existing cast, you have to specify a `USING` clause that tells PostgreSQL how to convert the values:

```
ALTER TABLE <tabname> ALTER <colname>
   SET DATA TYPE <newtype> USING <expression>;
```

Let's demonstrate that with an example. Suppose we have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE changeme(
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   d timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

It contains a few rows:

```
INSERT INTO changeme VALUES (1, current_timestamp);
INSERT INTO changeme VALUES (2, current_timestamp);
```

Now we want to convert the column `d` to a `bigint` that contains the number of seconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number).

Then we could do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE changeme ALTER d
   SET DATA TYPE bigint USING CAST(extract(epoch FROM d) AS bigint);
```